# Connect to a Postgresql db using ssl only

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I have a Postgresql server (Windows) that is supposed to ONLY accept SSL connections, but it doesn't.
This is the configuration of my pg_hba.conf file:

```
    # IPv4 local connections:
    hostssl all             all               0.0.0.0/0                 md5
```

This is the SSL part of postgresql.conf:

```
    # - SSL -

    ssl = on 
    #ssl_ca_file = ''
    ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
    #ssl_crl_file = ''
    ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
    #ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
    #ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
    #ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
    #ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
    #ssl_dh_params_file = ''
    #ssl_passphrase_command = ''
    #ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off
```

On all the posts I've read it seems that it is sufficient to activate the connection ONLY with SSL, however, if I connect from code with npgsql (c#) it requires SSL, if I use another program, for example DBeaver, it connects with SSL, but also WITHOUT SSL.
What did I do wrong? I would like to connect only with SSL and not without.
I hope I was clear.

I hope for a solution.

EDIT........
As requested by Adrian Klaver I add the entire pg_hba.conf file. I removed the entire top, which is just a comment and I don't think it's any use, this is what's left, nothing else.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                       md5
# IPv4 local connections:
hostnossl all           all               all                   reject
hostssl all             all               0.0.0.0/0               md5   
#hostssl all           Sa|vA@Dat1          0.0.0.0/0                trust  
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32              password
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                   password  
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
```

EDIT 2:
(The request of Adrian is too big for comment)
This is the connection log with SSL

```
connection authorized: user=xxxxx database=postgres SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.3, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256, compression=deactivated)
```

This is the connection log WITHOUT SSL

```
connection authorized: user=xxxxx database=postgres SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.3, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256, compression=deactivated)
```

They are IDENTICAL, I don't understand how it can happen, in the connection without SSL there are no references to the certificates and SSL is disabled. I'm testing with Dbeaver, but I don't think there are any differences with other tools

Comment: Do you also have a `host` line in pg_hba.conf?

Comment: @ Richard Huxton. No, that's the only line there, I know if there was a host line it would allow access, I removed everything on purpose

Comment: 1) You have other active lines in `pg_hab.conf`. Best bet is they start with `local`. 2) You are not connecting to the same Postgres instance in each case.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver, as I said, I deleted all the other lines to make sure they didn't cause problems, even the local one, which is only for unix, so I don't need it, there's only that line active. Of course I tried connections every time I deleted a row, but that never worked.

Comment: 1) Check the Postgres log to see what is happening. 2) How are you determining that DBeaver is not connecting with SSL? 3) What happens if you connect with `psql`?

Comment: @Adrian KlaverI said that Dbeaver always connects, with and without ssl, instead I expect it can ONLY connect with ssl

Comment: Again, check the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database. You may need to enable `log_connections` in `postgresql.conf` to see the connection information.

Comment: Should have added my suspicion is that DBeaver is setting `sslmode` to either `allow` or `prefer` per [JDBC SSL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/ssl/) when you are requesting no SSL.

Comment: How do you know dbeaver is not using SSL?  What specifically did you do to force this to be the case, or what thing you did you do after the fact to determine that this was the case?

Comment: @jjanes, in DBeaver there is a special section that says whether to use SSL or not.

Comment: @Adrian KlaverI The logging section in the postgresql.conf file is very long and complicated (for me), I'm trying to figure out how to set it up without damaging anything else.

Comment: Search for `log_connections`. If it is commented out, has `#` in front,  remove that and set to `log_connections = on`. While you are at it I would also do that that to the next line `log_disconnections = on`. Then reload or restart the server.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver I edit my question, the request is too long for comment.

Comment: See @jjanes answer. It is pretty plain that in DBeaver  when you uncheck `use SSL` it is setting the `sslmode` to either `allow` or `prefer`. Both of those settings will use a SSL  connection if SSL is enabled on the server, but will drop down to a non-SSL connection if that is all that is available. You need to follow the instructions in jjanes answer to create a `sslmode=disable` connection.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver If I understand correctly jjanes says to disable SSL in DBeaver, but my aim is not this, it is not to allow anyone to make connections without ssl, but maybe it's not possible.

Comment: And you have succeeded. As you showed DBeaver is using SSL to make a connection. To test use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and do something like `psql postgresql://localhost:5432/test?sslmode=disable`. You should get back *psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "aklaver", database "test", no encryption*. If you want to replicate with DBeaver follow @jjanes answer.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver You're right, it doesn't connect with psql:
FATAL: pg_hba.conf refuses connections for host '192.168.9.9', user 'G3Sc0N@pgres.user', database 'postgres', SSL not enabled.
I was just wasting my time due to my inexperience, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There must be another line in your `pg_hba.conf` that allows the unencrypted connections. To shut out such connections, add a line like this at the beginning:

```
hostnossl all all all reject
```

Comment: I did as you say, but it doesn't work.
Now the lines in pg_hba.conf look like this.
hostnossl all           all               all                   reject
hostssl all             all               0.0.0.0/0               md5

Comment: Then the solution is simple: either you edited the wrong file, or you didn't restart PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not like you say.

Comment: Perhaps you overlooked something in the file. Try adding the complete file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If all you did was uncheck the 'use SSL' box, that just means SSL is not mandatory for the client.  But it will still use it if the opportunity arises.

To forbid SSL, you need to (ironically) check 'use SSL' and then choose 'disable' from the mode drop-down list.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you mean and how to do it? I didn't understand, sorry.

Comment: I don't know how to make it clearer than I have already done.

Comment: If I understand correctly you mean to disable SSL in DBeaver, but my aim is not this, it is not to allow anyone to make connections without ssl, but perhaps it is not possible.